# How do I loop through a second value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to build a function that checks and returns an entry that matches its records.

Only issue is that there are 2 values (album_title and songs) in the dictionaries and I don't know how to loop through the 2nd value.

```
def make_album(artist, album_title, songs = None):
    A = {
    'artist1': 'album1', 'songs': '1'
    }
    
    B = {
    'artist2': 'album2', 'songs': '2'
    }
    
    C = {
    'artist3': 'album3', 'songs': '3'
    }

    dicts = [A, B, C]
    
    for dictionary in dicts:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if key == artist and value == album_title:
                print(dictionary)       
make_album('artist2', 'album2')
```

---

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "Only issue is that there are 2 values (album_title and songs) in the dictionaries and I don't know how to loop through the 2nd value." Those are **keys, not values**. The purpose of a dictionary is to **associate** a value with a key. It sounds as though you want to look at a dictionary, find out which **value** is **associated with** the `'album_title'` key and compare that to a reference; and also do the same for the `'songs'` key. That has *nothing to do with looping*. Just directly look up each of the two values.

Comment: Hint: given the dict `A = {'artist1': 'album1', 'songs': '1'}` - if you **only** want to get the value `'album1'` out of that, what code would you write? Would you use a loop? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like each `dict` here is really a pseudo-object describing describing an album. You don't want to iterate it at all, just perform lookups as needed.

So instead of:

```
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key == artist and value == album_title:
            print(dictionary)
```

you'd want something like:

```
    if dictionary.get(artist, None) == album_title:
        print(dictionary)
```

or roughly equivalently:

```
    if artist in dictionary and dictionary[artist] == album_title:
        print(dictionary)
```

Both of those do the same basic thing:

1. Check if the provided `artist` is a key in the `dict`, and
2. Verify that the album title associated with it matches the provided `album_title`

If both checks pass, you've found the album you were looking for. No need to loop at all, you just use the cheap membership tests and lookup-by-key features of `dict` to check the specific data you're interested in.

Once you know you've got a hit, you can just look up `dictionary['songs']` to get the value associated with that key.